# :after pseudo element different sizes from the same CSS selector

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a :after pseudo element that is placed below each of my nav bar buttons with one CSS selector, but for some reason it looks like the heights of the element underneath when you hover over the buttons "home" and "projects" are different from "about me" and "skills". Any idea as to why?

Here is a link to some code replicating the issue so you can see the different heights in question.

```css
.nav-button {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.nav-button:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #E7AB79;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, right 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

#home-button:hover:after {
  width: 68px;
  right: 0;
}

#aboutme-button:hover:after {
  width: 110px;
  left: 0;
}

#projects-button:hover:after {
  width: 90px;
  left: 0;
}

#skills-button:hover:after {
  width: 64px;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li class="nav-button button" id="home-button">Home</li>
    <li class="nav-button button" id="aboutme-button">About Me</li>
    <li class="nav-button button" id="projects-button">Projects</li>
    <li class="nav-button button" id="skills-button">Skills</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: issue screenshot]

Comment: @isherwood when you are hovering over the nav buttons, do all the elements underneath look the same height? I see two distinctly different heights for the elements under home/projects and about me/skills.

Comment: They do. Check your zoom level. You may be getting rounding variations if you're not at 100%.

Comment: My zoom is at 100%. I have added screenshots of what it looks like for me to the original post. Interesting that it's not happening for you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWzGr.png

Comment: What browser and OS?

Comment: chrome and windows 11

Comment: @isherwood thanks for the tip, I have changed them to anchors. Still seeing different heights though.

Comment: Try zooming in and out, I would expect you to see different lines having different heights at different zoom levels. Is that happening?

Comment: So if you hit `Ctrl-0` (zero) nothing changes? I'm on Chrome/Win10.

Comment: Protip: You can force hover state in Chrome's document inspector. This makes it easier to troubleshoot styles and capture comparative screenshots.

Comment: I guess its something with my screen settings? I just pulled out another laptop and it works fine. Still chrome windows 11. but on my other laptop the lines are off. Thanks for the hover tip, I added an updated screenshot. Since it's an isolated issue apparently just to my screen I won't worry about it too much then.

Comment: Does it happen in incognito mode?